# $n-$section formulas in goniometry without the calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

We know that the formulas of bisection of an angle $\alpha$ it is:

$$\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha}2\right)=\frac{1-\cos(\alpha)}{2}, \qquad \cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha}2\right)=\frac{1+\cos(\alpha)}{2}$$

In particular

$$\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}2\right)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\alpha)}{2}}, \qquad \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}2\right)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\alpha)}{2}}$$

**My question is:**

For the formulae of $n-$section of an angle $\alpha$, i.e.

$$\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}n\right), \qquad \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}n\right)$$

Do I must necessarily use the development in series of Taylor or the general formulas can be obtained with methods that do not use the derivatives, or the numerical methods?

My doubts arise for the students of an high school that not use the derivate.

Comment: The question is related to the constructibility of regular polygons with $n$ sides. Wantzel's theorem gives the answer. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightedge_and_compass_construction#Constructing_regular_polygons For instance, the value of $\cos \frac{2\pi}{17}$ with only square roots is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals#List_of_trigonometric_constants_of_2%CF%80/n). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you very much...can you, please, put your comment like an answer with a little personal and syntetic explanation? I like give the votes.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Don't worry.....:-) good rest. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer but I think it will be too long for a comment and moreover it gives you a explicit formula for the case when $n$ is a power of $2$:

For a given $\alpha$, let's call $\beta=\alpha/2$. Then your formula applied to $\beta/2$ reads

$$
\sin\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\beta)}{2}}.
$$

But $\beta=\alpha/2$ so we can apply agian the same formula:

$$
\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{4}\right) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{2}}= \pm\sqrt{\frac{1\mp\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\alpha)}{2}}}{2}} =\pm\sqrt{\frac{1\mp\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\alpha)}{2}}}{2}} .
$$

It can be simplified a little as

$$
\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{4}\right) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt 2 \mp\sqrt{1-\cos(\alpha)}}{2\sqrt 2}} .
$$

You can play the same game for $\gamma=\beta/2$. Undoing the change of variable, and if I am not mistaken, the formula should be

$$
\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{8}\right) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{2\sqrt2 \mp\sqrt{\sqrt2\mp \sqrt{1-\cos(\alpha)}}}{2\sqrt{2\sqrt2}}} .
$$

To get the general formula, it is better to denote square roots by $2^{1/2}$, so that $\sin(\alpha/8)$ becomes

$$
\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{8}\right) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{2^{1+1/2} \mp\sqrt{2^{1/2}\mp \sqrt{2^0-\cos(\alpha)}}}{2^{1+1/2+1/4}}} .
$$

And there you go:

$$
\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2^m}\right) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{2^{2^{1-(m-1)}\left(2^{m-1})-1\right)} \mp\sqrt{2^{2^{1-(m-2)}\left(2^{m-2})-1\right)} \mp \sqrt{\cdots \sqrt{1-\cos(\alpha)}}}}{2^{2^{1-m}\left(2^m-1\right)}}} .
$$

**Remark.** I am using the fact that

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{1}{2^k} = 2^{1-m}\left(2^m-1\right)
$$

Comment: I very much appreciate with true enthusiasm the answers. +1 and...if I remember correctly is it a geometric series of ratio $\frac{1}{2}$? I not remember that the sum is $2^{1-m}\left(2^m-1\right)$ :-(.

Comment: @Sebastiano Indeed, it is! And to be honest, I did not apply the formula, but used WolframAlpha instead, which might have "simplified" the final expression. Use your formula and try to show both results are the same.

Comment: In $2^{1+1/2}$ I suggest to use \frac :-)

Comment: Hi, there are of the strange downvotes for my question and your answer.

Comment: Yes, I don't know. Someone who didn't like it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, with very large values of $n$, you will get
$$\sin(x)=\text{polynomial in $\sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ or $\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$  or both with a very large degree}$$
where the degree of a polynomial is the highest power in it, for example the degree of $x^2+3x+5$ is $2$.

However, we don't general formulae for any general polynomial equation with degree greater than or equal to $5$ then I guess for $n\ge5$ what you ask is indeed impossible.

I have no rigorous response to Bumblebee's point, but the following formulae makes it seem unlikely for your question to have 'yes, it's possible at least sometimes (apart from the trivial cases)' for an answer.
$$\begin{align}
\sin(n\theta) &= \sum_{k\text{ odd}} (-1)^\frac{k-1}{2} {n \choose k}\cos^{n-k} \theta \sin^k \theta, \\
\cos(n\theta) &= \sum_{k\text{ even}} (-1)^\frac{k}{2} {n \choose k}\cos^{n-k} \theta \sin^k \theta \,,
\end{align}$$

Comment: What if those polynomials are solvable in radicals?

Comment: Thank you very much...I have not understood well your answer but do you explain better your answer with some examples, please?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: There is no such general formula. But there are polynomials solvable in radicals. For example $x^5-1=0.$

Comment: @Bumblebee I see your point, thanks. Do you think I should delete my answer?

Comment: @Sebastiano I have edited my answer. Is that any clearer? However, my answer is flawed, so I may consider deleting it; see Bumblebee's comments.

Comment: In the meantime upvoted this $\ddot\smile$.

Comment: @Sebastiano thanks, I'm not sure I deserve it! Hopefully someone else will have a better answer.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent I am poor in English language: but the binomial development you wrote me refers to the $n$-plication formulas or am I wrong. Duplication, triplication, etc.?

Comment: This is unsound. Take $n=2$. Then $$\sin(x)=\sin(2\cdot x/2)=2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)=2\sin(x/2)\sqrt{1-\sin(x/2)^2},$$ which is not a polynomial function of $\sin(x/2)$. The closest version of this I know is via the Chevyshev polynomials: $U_n(\cos \theta)=\dfrac{\sin((n+1)\theta)}{\sin\theta}$ where $U_n$ is the $n$th Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind. In simpler terms: The ratio $\dfrac{\sin x}{\sin(x/n)}$ is a degree-$(n-1)$ polynomial in $\cos(x/n)$. By contrast, for cosine one has $\cos(n\theta)=T_n(\cos\theta)$ for the Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind.

Comment: @Semiclassical where have I contradicted what you wrote in my answer? I am not being confrontational; I'm simply not sure where you have encountered a problem in my answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano yes; if you let $x=\frac{u}{n}$ it may be clearer.

Comment: Let $y=\sin(x/2)$. Then $\sin(x)=2y\sqrt{1-y^2}$, which is not a polynomial function of $y$. Hence $\sin(x)$ is not a polynomial function of $\sin(x/2)$, regardless of your degree. (By contrast, $\sin^2 x=4y(1-y^2)$. So $\sin^2 x$ does a polynomial form.) More generally, one has $\sin(x)=p(\sin(x/n))\sqrt{1-\sin(x/n)^2}$. So this isn't so easily remedied.

Comment: @Semiclassical Oh, that was stupid of me, I will fix the error.

Comment: The claim appears to be now that $\sin(x)=f(\sin(x/n),\cos(x/n))$ for some bivariate polynomial $f$. I think that's true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118543/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-a-level-student).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there are such elementary general formulas. I will derive a possible (restricted) formula as an infinite series using [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), though this may not satisfy your requirement of calculus free derivation. One value of the multivalued expression $\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta}{n}\right),\quad n\ge2$ is given by
\begin{align}
\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{1/n} & 
= \left(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\right)^{1/n} \\
 & = \left(\cos\theta\right)^{1/n}\left(1+i\tan\theta\right)^{1/n}
\end{align}

Now, assuming $0\lt\theta\lt\pi/4,$ we can expand $\left(1+i\tan\theta\right)^{1/n}$ via [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) as $$1+\dfrac{1}{n}i\tan\theta +\dfrac{(n-1)}{2!n^2}\tan^2\theta -\dfrac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{3!n^3}i\tan^3\theta -\dfrac{(n-1)(2n-1)(3n-1)}{4!n^4}\tan^4\theta +\cdots.$$

Hence we have two infinite series $$\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta}{n}\right)}{\sqrt[n]{\cos\theta}}=\dfrac{1}{n}\tan\theta - \dfrac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{3!n^3}\tan^3\theta+ \dfrac{(n-1)(2n-1)(3n-1)(4n-1)}{5!n^5}\tan^5\theta+$$ and
$$\dfrac{\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta}{n}\right)}{\sqrt[n]{\cos\theta}}=1+\dfrac{(n-1)}{2!n^2}\tan^2\theta-\dfrac{(n-1)(2n-1)(3n-1)}{4!n^4}\tan^4\theta +\cdots.$$

Comment: I have understood your path but for my students your process is impossible. The question was also a curiosity of mine since I could expand in series. However.....thank youuuuuuuuu very very much. +1